# Catalogue versioning

Tags: data-versioning

Apologies if this is not the right SE site to ask.

I'm designing an application for catalogue management.
Any element in the hierarchy has to be versioned, i.e. when I change a property of it, a new version is created. The new version can also have different children than the previous. The user can switch between versions when she manages the catalogue, so I'll need to list all the existing versions of a child. When switching version, all the descendant will be updated).

My first thought was something like

```
| A            |  | B            |  | C            |
|--------------|  |--------------|  |--------------|
| ID  (k)      |  | ID  (k)      |  | ID  (k)      |
| VER (k)      |  | VER (k)      |  | VER (k)      |
| ...          |  | A_ID (fk)    |  | B_ID (fk)    |
|              |  | A_VER (fk)   |  | B_VER (fk)   |
|--------------|  | ...          |  | ...          |
                  |--------------|  |--------------|
```

Where the entities' key is always something like (ID, VER) and the parent's fk is (P_ID, P_VER).

Is this a good way to implement it?

**Update**: It's apparently more complicate than that. The meaning of the versioning is that elements have a validity time and we need to keep the older version. E.g. a client buys product with price x. After 1 January it's gonna cost y.
New clients after 1 January get new price y, but old client keeps paying x.

Adding a timestamp column is probably the best option here.

Comment: Something along the lines of [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)?

Comment: A simple incremental number is enough. Any change will increase the version by 1.

Comment: You might end up with duplicated version if 2 people try to change it at the same time. An id with identity is probably better.

Comment: @JulienVavasseur What you mean by "id with identity"?

Comment: 2 personne try to update id X at the same time. The code increment ver V on each computer and both of them try to create a new row with id=x and ver = V+1. where you declare your table, you give it a type with incremental number such as identity(0, 1) with sql server or I think sequence with Oracle.

Comment: just an Id which will be automatically incremented by the Database. Which RDBMS will you use?

Comment: There will be some logic to determine if it's a new version or not and we'll have to manage concurrency somehow. But that's not the problem. I'm trying to determine the best way to model this type of data.

Comment: When the parent increments the version, what happens with the children? If you had one parent in table a, two children in table b, and then two children each in table c, when table a is incremented, would it have to make a copy of the table A.v1 children in b and c? So then you would have two records in a, 4 in b, and 8 in c?

Comment: @batetech the PM is actually still deciding if we are going to version the entire catalogue or each single component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be quite honest your requirements sound like a cross between a nightmare and a [Version Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).  I would highly recommend looking at popular solutions like [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) instead of reimplementing a [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) with a relational database.  Your application could effectively be a nice skin around Git.  **If you have to do this via a relational database** then I think versioning by time stamps is going to be your best chance of success.

The basic strategy is to put a time stamp on every entity.  Then when you need to go to the most recent version you select all the entities through the relational chain with the most recent time stamp.  When you need to get a specific version you grab all the most recent versions of the entities that are at or older than the version time stamp you want.

Versioning by time stamp prevents you from copying all the older entities to a new version id even if those entities haven't changed.  It also saves you the madness of keeping track of those version ids.

This might lead to slow query times but you can play with it to see if it suits your needs.  To reiterate I don't think a relational database is the best solution, but sometimes life forces us to put the square peg in the round hole.  If that is your lot in life I wish you the best.

**Edit:** Versioning is related to historical pricing

I agree that time stamps are the way to go given that versioning is related to historical pricing.  To handle that you just need an Effective Start Date column.  To find the rate at any point in time you just need to find the most recent date that isn't in the future.  For example:

```
declare @Date DATE = SYSUTCDATETIME(); -- Or any other date for historical/future data
;with [CurrentPrice_CTE] AS -- You don't really need this semi-colon but I added it as a defensive habit.
(
    select
      [PriceId] -- Price table's PK
      max([EffectiveStartDate]) AS [EffectiveStartDate]
    from [dbo].[Price]
    where
      [EffectiveStartDate] <= @Date
)
select
  [p].* -- Select the columns you need
from [dbo].[prices] [p]
    inner join [CurrentPrice_CTE] [cp] as [cp].[PriceId] = [p].[PriceId] and [cp].[EffectiveStartDate] = [p].[EffectiveStartDate]
```

Just make sure you make the start date unique for each product or that code will return more results than you want.  To be totally honest this sounds like a much less complicated problem than having to reversion the entire database every update.  :)

Comment: Your solution sounds interesting, but I don't understand how I can apply it to my problem. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @algiogia On git, time stamps, or both?

Comment: On GIT. We are actually considering representing the catalogue as XML (easier to maintain the hierarchy) so we may version the file.

Comment: @algiogia After reading your update I totally agree that time stamps are the way to go.  I updated my answer with some sample code that should be close to what you might need.  Overall I think this is a much nicer set of requirements than your original question lead me to believe. :)